# Creating Dynamic combobox with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add dynamically a combobox using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044104/how-to-add-dynamically-a-combobox-using-jquery)

Look, I've this working code for dynamic comboboxs.

```
<html>
<div id="combos" class="styled-select">
<select id="combo1" class="combo" data-index="1">
<option></option>
<option>sss</option>
<option>aaa</option>
<option>ddd</option>
</select>
</div>

<script>
$('#combos').on('change', '.combo', function () {
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();

        if ($(this).find('option').size() > 2) {
            var newComboBox = $(this).clone();
            var thisComboBoxIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'), 2);
            var newComboBoxIndex = thisComboBoxIndex + 1;
            $('.parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex).remove();
            if (selectedValue !== '') 
            {
            newComboBox.attr('data-index', newComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.attr('id', 'combo' + newComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.addClass('parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.find('option[value="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
            $('#combos').append(newComboBox);
            }
        }
        });
</script>
</html>
```

What this does is create a new one combobox everytime I fill the combobox before.

What Im looking for is that code create 2 comboboxs everytime I fill the combobox before, instead just one.

How could I do that?

Cheers

Comment: Consider using `body` and `head` tags for your invalid page. Can you provide a demo on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @undefined http://jsfiddle.net/JaVVe/6/

Comment: This question seems exactly the same as this one from @skdnewbie: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14044104/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this what you want but this adds two combo boxes
(after $('#combos').append(newComboBox);):

```
var otherComboBox = $('#combo' + newComboBoxIndex).clone();
otherComboBox.attr('id', 'othercombo' + newComboBoxIndex);
$('body').append(otherComboBox);
```