# How to add dynamically a combobox using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I've this working code which is creating **one** combobox:

You can see it working here: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JaVVe/6/)**

```
$('body').on('change', '.combo', function() {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();

    if ($(this).find('option').size() > 2) {
        var newComboBox = $(this).clone();
        var thisComboBoxIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'), 10);
        var newComboBoxIndex = thisComboBoxIndex + 1;

        $('.parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex).remove();

        if (selectedValue !== '') {
            newComboBox.attr('data-index', newComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.attr('id', 'combo' + newComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.addClass('parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex);
            newComboBox.find('option[val="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
            $('body').append(newComboBox);
        }
    }
});
```

Which is resulting something this, everytime I fill a combobox, the next one is opened.

[image: one combobox only]

How can I change that code to have this? Which means two comboboxes opening (please forget the *style*)

[image: Which means two comboboxes effect]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if your intent, but it seems like you want to have groups of two `select` elements and then adding a new group when the user selects a value.

In that case I suggest grouping your two `select`s in a `fieldset` like this:

```
<fieldset>
  <select id="combo1" class="combo" data-index="1">
    <option></option>
    <option val="Opt1">Opt1</option>
    <option val="Opt2">Opt2</option>
    <option val="Opt3">Opt3</option>
  </select>
  <select id="combo2" class="combo" data-index="2">
    <option></option>
    <option val="Opt1">Opt1</option>
    <option val="Opt2">Opt2</option>
    <option val="Opt3">Opt3</option>
  </select>
</fieldset>
```

​
And then looking up that parent `fieldset` and cloning it like this:

```
$('body').on('change', '.combo', function() {
  var selectedValue = $(this).val();

  var fieldset = $(this).parents('fieldset');

  if ($(this).find('option').size() > 2) {
    var newFieldset = fieldset.clone();
    var newComboBox = $(fieldset).children('.combo:first');
    var thisComboBoxIndex = parseInt($(this).attr('data-index'), 10);
    var newComboBoxIndex = thisComboBoxIndex + 1;

    $('.parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex).remove();

    if (selectedValue !== '') {
        newComboBox.attr('data-index', newComboBoxIndex);
        newComboBox.attr('id', 'combo' + newComboBoxIndex);
        newComboBox.addClass('parentCombo' + thisComboBoxIndex);
        newComboBox.find('option[val="' + selectedValue + '"]').remove();
        $('body').append(newFieldset);
    }
  }     
});​
```

There are some details probably not exactly the way you need it, but in general this is the approach I'd recomment.

Find the updated Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JaVVe/8/

Comment: your approach fled a bit to what I had thought. If you play a bit in your fiddle it seems very confusing. My point is just open 2 comboboxes everytime the combobox before is filled with something. As you seen, I got it working but just for 1 combo :s

Comment: You could forget the fact of content being filtered everytime that a new combobox is opened. Lets think that the content will be allways the same for now.

Comment: My answer/fiddle shows one way to open sets of `select`s: by grouping them into a `fieldset`. When you select a value in one of the `select`s it opens an additional group. Note that HTML does **not** have a (built-in) combo box, these are simple `select` controls. A combo box would combine a drop down list with an edit control, these days typically associated with "autocomplete". If you have additional questions about the code, I'd be happy to answer. Just ask here or update your original question.

Comment: Ok using your fiddle, why sometimes options stays blank when selected?

Comment: That was caused by some of your original code that I didn't update (the innermost `if`). If I remove that the behavior becomes a lot simpler: http://jsfiddle.net/JaVVe/10/

Comment: it is becoming close what I could work out. Using your new example, there is someway to just create the next combobox if the 2 before were completed? Am i explaining well?

Comment: You are explaining it perfectly. I suggest you take the code I wrote for you and now try to make it do what you want. If you get stuck, I can answer questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to double the amount of combo boxes you could use a for-loop and set their values depending on the value of the counter-variable.